# NodeJS Error when sending response back

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm making a simple Rest service that has to add into the database (MongoDB) the data that comes in the JSON request. The problem is occuring when I make a request to the service, the server goes down with the following error:

> controller@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller
>   node ./bin/www
>
> { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
>   js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
>   POST /controller/addagent 200 25.762 ms - 0
>   _http_outgoing.js:335
>       throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
>             ^
>   **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
>       at Promise. (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\routes\controller.js:26:15)
>       at Promise. (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:178:8)
>       at Promise.emit (events.js:129:20)
>       at Promise.emit (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
>       at Promise.fulfill (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
>       at Promise.resolve (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:126:15)
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\node_modules\monk\lib\collection.js:343:23)
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! controller@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the controller@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the controller package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls controller
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fernando\Google Drive\TCC_Fernando_Felipe\Controller\controller\npm-debug.log

The code on the server side is:

**controller.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a controller');
});

/*
 * POST to adduser.
 */
**router.post('/addagent', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('controller');
    var agents = req.body.agents;

    if(agents.length && agents.length >0)
    {
         for(var i=0; i < agents.length; ++i){
                var cAgent = agents[i];

                collection.insert(cAgent, function(err, result){
                res.send(
                    (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
                );
            });
        }
    }


});**

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Added for database connection
var mongo=require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/controller');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var controller = require('./routes/controller')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/controller',controller);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

The error seems to be caused by the line block below. I'm not sure why, as the res variable is only accessed at that moment.

```
res.send(
                    (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending data multiple times using res.send().So this error is occurred.
try this one:

```
router.post('/addagent', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('controller');
var agents = req.body.agents;
var count=1;
if(agents.length && agents.length >0)
{
     for(var i=0; i < agents.length; ++i){
            var cAgent = agents[i];

            collection.insert(cAgent, function(err, result){
            if(err)
               res.send({ msg: err });
            else{
              count++;
              if(count== agents.length){
                 res.send(
                     { msg: '' }
                 );
              }
            }
        });
    }
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was the for, that was trying to send res.send() multiple times.

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should accept your own answer and close the question